# Pasar valores de checkboxes desde mi plantilla a mi funcion y guardarlos en mi db mysql

Tags: html, python, mysql, django

tengo una base de datos y una tabla en django, y quiero que en un   se muestre la posibilidad de elegir entre dos opciones: "triste y feliz" y se guarde en la base de datos y persista en la pagina web.
intente con la funcion

```
<td>
                    <style>
                        .selected {
                          background-color:rgba(161, 151, 151, 0.719);
                        }
                      </style>

                      <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="{{ nota.satisfaccion }}_checkit" id="{{ nota.satisfaccion }}_feliz" value="feliz" style="display:none;">
                        <span style="color:green;" class="material-symbols-outlined" onclick="document.querySelector('#{{ nota.satisfaccion }}_feliz').click();document.querySelectorAll('.material-symbols-outlined').forEach(function (el) {el.classList.remove('selected')}); this.classList.add('selected');">
                          sentiment_very_satisfied
                        </span>

                      </label>

                      <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="{{ nota.satisfaccion }}_checkit" id="{{ nota.satisfaccion }}_triste" value="triste" style="display:none;">
                        <span style="color:red;" class="material-symbols-outlined" onclick="document.querySelector('#{{ nota.satisfaccion }}_triste').click();document.querySelectorAll('.material-symbols-outlined').forEach(function (el) {el.classList.remove('selected')}); this.classList.add('selected');">
                          sentiment_very_dissatisfied
                        </span>

                      </label>


                  </td>

<script>
    const feliz = document.querySelector('#{{ nota.satisfaccion }}_feliz');
    const triste = document.querySelector('#{{ nota.satisfaccion }}_triste');

    feliz.parentElement.addEventListener('click', () => {
      feliz.checked = true;
    });

    triste.parentElement.addEventListener('click', () => {
      triste.checked = true;
    });
  </script>
```

y diversas formas parecidas pero no me funciona.

Answer (score 0):

tienes que usar ajax.

create un endpoint como este:

```
path('update_satisfaccion/', views.update_satisfaccion, name='update_satisfaccion'),
```

...que sera el encargado de actualziar la BD cuando cambies el valor.

y modifica los imput:

```
<input type="radio" name="{{ nota.satisfaccion }}_checkit" id="{{ nota.satisfaccion }}_feliz" value="feliz" style="display:none;" data-id="{{ nota.id }}" data-csrf="{{ csrf_token }}">
<input type="radio" name="{{ nota.satisfaccion }}_checkit" id="{{ nota.satisfaccion }}_triste" value="triste" style="display:none;" data-id="{{ nota.id }}" data-csrf="{{ csrf_token }}">
```

la función con la solicitud ajax y la vista de django no te las pongo, son algo más extensas, pero ya sabes, no tiene mucho secreto, que haga la llamada a esa ruta de django.